# Cannot call method 'append' of null

Tags: jquery, html

Got this weird issue with Using jQuery 1.6.0 issue. I am trying to append some content to a div, if the user has typed more than 3 chars in a text box.

Here is my JS

```
$('#Form_pickForm_Name').keyup(function() {
  var searched = $('Form_pickForm_Name').value;
  if (searched.length > 2) {
    // Add the name_suggestions if doesn't exit
    if ($("name_suggestions").length < 1){
        $('#Name').append("<div id='name_suggestions'>Foo!</div>");
    }
  }
});
```

And this is the relevant HTML

```
<div id="Name" class="field text ">
    <label class="left" for="Form_pickForm_Name">Your Full Name</label>
    <div class="middleColumn">
        <input type="text" class="text" id="Form_pickForm_Name" name="Name" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I have checked the page, and there is no other id="Name" on it.

If I `alert($('#Name'));` I get null, but if I `alert($('Name'))` I get [object HTMLDivElement] but it still wont let me append.

Using jQuery 1.6.0

Comment: Because there are some "#" missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have syntax errors, try this method (selector without #)... please use the val() method instead value:

```
$('#Form_pickForm_Name').keyup(function() {
  var searched = $('#Form_pickForm_Name').val();
  if (searched.length > 2) {
    // Add the name_suggestions if doesn't exit
    if ($("#name_suggestions").length < 1){
    $('#Name').append("<div id='name_suggestions'>Foo!</div>");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the # was the issue, but the key for me was val() as I was using that to test, and value would be null so I was thinking it was the selector!

Answer (score 1):

I have switched to using an appendTo, I think you need the `$` object to create an element.

Also, there are some syntax errors (missing hashes off two ID's)

```
$('#Form_pickForm_Name').keyup(function() {
  var searched = $('#Form_pickForm_Name').value;
  if (searched.length > 2) {
    // Add the name_suggestions if doesn't exit
    if ($("#name_suggestions").length < 1){
        $("<div id='name_suggestions'>Foo!</div>").appendTo("#Name");

    }
  }
});
```